# How to search by a part of string field value in firestore document?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a couple of documents in my firestore and there exists a filed name, 'date' which is a string and which is in each and every document.

this is the structure of the field of three documents with values.

```
date:"2020.01.18" (document 1)
date: "2020.01.19" (document 2)
date: "2020.02.17" (document 3)
```

I want to query all the documents which have the date as "2020.01" / "2020.02" (ignoring the day. Only select data from the year and month)

This is what I was trying to do

```
this.afs
      .collection("orders", ref => ref.where("date", '==', date)) //How should I change the condition ('==') in here to overcome with this problem.
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your dates are in a format where the lexicographical order is the same as the chronological order, you can use Firestore's range filters to query on a date range.

If you're looking for documents in January or February of 2020, that'd be:

```
ref.where('date', '>=', '2020.01.01').where('date', '<', '2020.03.01')
```

---

You could even leave off the day part of values, and get the same result:

```
ref.where('date', '>=', '2020.01.').where('date', '<', '2020.03.')
```

This is because Firestore queries do a prefix match for range operations on strings.

One more example: to get all documents in 2020:

```
ref.where('date', '>=', '2020').where('date', '<', '2021')
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution #1: Add an extra field

One possible solution would be to add an extra field to your documents, with only the year and month, as follows:

```
date:"2020.01.18" (document 1)
searchDate:"2020.01" (document 1)
date: "2020.01.19" (document 2)
searchDate:"2020.01" (document 2)
date: "2020.02.17" (document 3)
searchDate:"2020.02" (document 3)
```

Then you can easily query on this field:

```
this.afs
      .collection("orders", ref => ref.where("searchDate", '==', "2020.02"))
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

Duplicating data this way is quite classic in NoSQL World, in order to simplify/optimize query processing. It follows a similar "philosophy" than *Denormalization*, which is also a classic approach, as explained in this [article](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) about "Data modeling techniques" for NoSQL databases

---

#### Solution #2: Use a specific Unicode character to simulate an SQL LIKE 'YYYY.MM.%'

Another solution would be to use a combination of `orderBy()`, `startAt()` and `endAt()` (see the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=0)) together with the character `\uf8ff` as follows

```
var searchString = '2020.02.'   
this.afs
      .collection("orders", ref => ref.orderBy('searchDate')
      .startAt(searchString)
      .endAt(searchString + '\uf8ff'))
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

As a matter of facts, the character `\uf8ff` is after most regular characters in Unicode, therefore the query matches all values that start with `searchString`.

---

Note that in case you want to build a OR query (i.e.  all the documents which have the date as "2020.01" **OR** as "2020.02" ), it not possible in Firestore, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations). You should "create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app".

Comment: @IlthizamImtiyas Thanks for having accepted my answer but you should note Frank's answer which is definitely more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

the way these queries work is by indexes that firestore keeps, I don't think that this is possible however an alternative solution is to cache the values on your local storage and serve them to the client

check to this cool service below:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235822/angular-fire-firestore-cached-service